# How to mix textures with colour?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I am attempting to add a logo to a metal material.
Unfortunately, when I render it, it has no color.

[image]

I fed the metal shader and the logo's image texture to a mix shader.
Then I used the same image texture as the fac input.
It has colour in material viewport mode, but not when rendered.

Oddly, if I  feed the image texture only into the fac input and not as a shader, it makes no difference to the render.

The upper 3d view is rendered, the lower is material viewport mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent image like a decal on mesh with principled BSDF shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99266/transparent-image-like-a-decal-on-mesh-with-principled-bsdf-shader/104376#104376) and  [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material)

Answer (score 2):

Realized the answer 5 minutes after posting.

I was trying to mix a texture with a shader.
I needed to mix two materials together.
So I simply added a Principled shader with the logo in its colour input.
[image]

Comment: You don't need the second metallic shader. All of this can be done directly using the Principled shader only.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Rather than using a texture to mix a Principled metal shader and a Principled wood shader, I can use that texture in the metallic input of a single Principled shader. A MixRGB node with the same texture in the fac input will do the same for the colours.