# How do I put a drawing or image above the texture of my material in blender cycles 2.8

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image, shaders

Basically if I have this texture [image]

and I want to add the blender logo. How do I do it?

Comment: Use an image that has an alpha channel and then read this: [Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46447/1853)

Comment: A different explanation of the same: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99266/transparent-image-like-a-decal-on-mesh-with-principled-bsdf-shader