# Why is my asset appearing as non-transparent?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, transparency

[image]

[image]

[image]

I just downloaded a 3d plant asset in FBX format from Megascans and this is the way my model appears.

[image]

The wheat seems to not be flat, and non-transparent. How do I make it transparent around the grains, and not as rectangular?

Comment: I'm really sorry I thought the picture was added. I'm new to this so it was a bit confusing at first but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @susu I have edited the question to make it more clear, please review the question again.

Comment: Many thanks for reviewing my question. It's really appreciated.

Comment: Set the material's Blend Mode to Alpha Clip or Alpha Hashed. Also make sure the alpha socket is connected.

Comment: I did try this and connecting the alpha socket to albido.jpg, opacity.jpg and translucency.jpg 1 by 1 but still showing the rectangular shape.

Comment: None of the images you are using has an alpha channel. The transparency has to come from somewhere. Do you have a transparency map? That is the one that should be plugged to the alpha input on the Principled BSDF shader. Else try plugging the "translucency" and see if that works.

Comment: I don't have the transparency map and I tried with the translucent map and it doesn't work when I plug it into the principal BSDF - alpha

Comment: The alpha (transparency) has to come from somewhere. Blender will not create it magically for you.

Comment: Sorry Im new to this but I will do my best to learn fast, I checked in the export setting in megasacans and I can add those map: MASK, TRANSMISSION, FUZZ ? but I don't see the transparency map

Comment: What does the opacity map look like?

Comment: The opacity map got black and white information, I did try to link it with the alpha from the shader BSDF and change in material setting alpha clip or alpha rashed but still I don't see any result

Comment: Are you connecting the Color socket of the opacity map to the Alpha socket on the Principled node?

Comment: Thanks so much I did what you said about the opacity colour socket to the alpha from the principal BSDF and it works.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the material, nothing is connected to the alpha input of the shader. Connect this, and then make sure in the material settings that alpha mode is set to “hashed” and not “opaque”.

Answer (score 1):

To have "transparency" you need some form of mask or map for it.

Let's say you have two images:

1- The color information

2 - A "Transparency" or "Opaque" map, which would be a black and white image that determines what is "see through" (black) and what is opaque (white).

Usually this information is embedded in an "Alpha" channel, but since you are dealing with the worst possible format (jpeg) there is no alpha channel.

[image]

To use the transparency, use an image texture node and plug it to the alpha socket of the Principled BSDF.

[image]

Read also:

[Add a transparent image on top of a material](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material/46447#46447)

[Transparent image like a decal on mesh with principled BSDF shader](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99266/transparent-image-like-a-decal-on-mesh-with-principled-bsdf-shader/104376#104376)